# Intent.putExtra not working on second activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

My EXTRA_REPLY variable is not storing information, it is used exactly like another variable called EXTRA_MESSAGE. The string simply isn't storing into my EXTRA_REPLY

Walkthrough

Testing this, the toast clearly shows that EXTRA_REPLY variable is not storing my reply string because there is nothing (null) coming up, the toast on my other activity works (it displays the string that I type into the editText_main field.

fun returnReply(view: View) {

```
    val replyIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

    val reply = "${editText_second.text}"

    replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, reply)
    setResult(RESULT_OK,replyIntent)

    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_REPLY), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    finish()

}
```

}

---

This is the toast from the first activity which shows that the EXTRA_MESSAGE intent logs in my message string. This is the one that shows the string while the other returns null

fun launchSecondActivity(view: View) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Button clicked!")

```
    val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)



    val message = "${editText_main.text}"


    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)

    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()



    startActivityForResult(intent, TEXT_REQUEST)

    editText_main.text.clear()

}
```

---

This is my intent receiver that receives the intent data from the first code snippet. I don't know if this works until the EXTRA_REPLY variable stores information successfully. As stated before, EXTRA_MESSAGE does in fact, store my string.

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int,
    data: Intent?
) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

   if (requestCode == TEXT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {



            val reply = intent.getStringExtra(SecondActivity().EXTRA_REPLY)




            (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_header_reply) as TextView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            (findViewById(R.id.text_message_reply) as TextView).setText(reply)




        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `EXTRA_REPLY` ? How did you define it?

Comment: This is the way I defined it:

 val EXTRA_REPLY = "com.example.android.twoactivities.extra.REPLY"

Comment: `My EXTRA_REPLY variable is not storing information, it is used exactly like another variable called EXTRA_MESSAGE.` No. You use them complete different.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(applicationContext, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_REPLY), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()` What do you see with this toast?

Comment: `replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, reply)` Maybe `reply==null` Try with `replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, "this is my message")`.